# Validate a chain of mappers types

Tags: typescript, mapper

I want to validate a chain/array of mappers at type level. The idea is that for each mapper the output should match the input of the next mapper in the list. And the first input and last output are validated by the `ChainedMappers<From, To>` generics.

So for example:

- `correctMappers` is OK as it follows the chain: `A -> B -> C -> D`.
- But `incorrectMappers` should FAIL because a mapper is missing: `A -> B xxx C -> D`.

I've tried with recursive types… but couldn't solve it. **Is it doable?**

```
interface Mapper<From, To> {
  map(from: From): To;
}

type A = /* ... */;
type B = /* ... */;
type C = /* ... */;
type D = /* ... */;

const mapperAB: Mapper<A, B> = /* ... */;
const mapperBC: Mapper<B, C> = /* ... */;
const mapperCD: Mapper<C, D> = /* ... */;

const correctMappers: ChainedMappers<A, D> = [
  mapperAB,
  mapperBC,
  mapperCD,
];

const incorrectMappers: ChainedMappers<A, D> = [
  mapperAB,
  // !!! Missing mapper from B to C !!!
  mapperCD,
];
```

Comment: What use is a variable of type `ChainedMappers<A, D>` which forgets intermediate types? Conceptually it's like a `Mapper<A, D>`, but it isn't one; it's just an array of forgotten links. It seems either you just want a `ChainableMapper` that provides a `then` method like [this](//tsplay.dev/w6e2eW), or you want a more complicated `ChainedMappers<[A, B, C, D]>` that you can use to verify the full chain like [this](//tsplay.dev/w8gvdW). Do either of those approaches meet your needs? If so, I'll write up an answer; if not, please [edit] to show how you'd imagine using a `ChainedMappers<A, D>`.

Comment: This is used to map to the latest version of a document schema (in a DB without migrations), so each time that a document is read from the DB is mapped from `v0 -> v1 -> v2 …` to the latest version (and if it's written is stored to the latest version). The `ChainedMappers` array is used by a class that upgrades the document. From both options I like the `ChainedMappers<[A, B, C, D]>` one the most… it would be magical if it worked implicitly, but I can live with the explicit chain. Nice solution 